# Limit how many resources can be used

Tags: anylogic

I have to limit how many resources can be used by Agents. For example, I have to limit that one cashier can serve n amount of customers, then it is disabled. My cashiers are in a resource pool with a capacity of 3, so 3 cashiers can serve only n amount of clients each, then they get disabled. A Service block is using the resource pool of cashiers. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the cashier is a resource agent of type Cashier
each cashier can have a variable in it, called "customersServed" of type int
and a variable called "enabled" of type boolean initially true

then each time a resource is seized:

```
((Cashier)unit).customersServed++;
```

and when the resource is released:

```
if(((Cashier)unit).customersServed>n){
    ((Cashier)unit).enabled=false;
}
```

finally, in your resourcePool check the "customize resource" box and use this condition:

```
((Cashier)unit).enabled
```